# How to set focus on a checkbox when it is grouped with radio buttons inside a composite control

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have created composite control that has check box and  two radio buttons.This is something like controlling radio buttons with a check box, i.e. radios will be enabled only after check box selected

I want to set the focus on the check box when the page comes up(using CTRl+TAB for composite traversal), it works fine in the case of none of radio buttons are enabled.

If any of the radio button is selected then focus is going to that radio button but not to the **checked** box.Is this windows default behavior, focus should be on selected radio button ??
How can i make focus should always be on check box ??
I tried to use setFocus on checkbox, but that didnt help.

All these three buttons are in a group.

Here is the sample code

```
    Composite composite = this;

    GridData LData = new GridData();
    LData.horizontalSpan = 1;
    LData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    LData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    LData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    LData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    composite.setLayoutData(LData);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Label infoLabel = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    infoLabel.setText("Test");  

    rGroup = new Group(composite, SWT.NONE);    
    GridData rGroupLData = new GridData();
    rGroupLData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    rGroupLData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    rGroup.setLayoutData(rGroupLData);
    GridLayout rGroupLayout = new GridLayout(5, false);
    rGroup.setLayout(rGroupLayout);

    checkBox1 = new Button(rGroup, SWT.CHECK);
    checkBox1.setText("CheckBox");
    GridData rcheckBox1LData = new GridData();
    rcheckBox1LData.horizontalSpan = 5;
    rcheckBox1LData.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
    rcheckBox1LData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    rcheckBox1LData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    checkBox1.setLayoutData(rcheckBox1LData);

    GridData r1LData  = new GridData();
    r1LData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
    r1LData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    r1LData.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;

    r1Numeric = new Button(rGroup, SWT.RADIO);
    r1Numeric.setText("Radio1");
    r1Numeric.setSelection(true);
    r1Numeric.setLayoutData(r1LData);
    r1Numeric.setEnabled(false);        

    GridData selR1LData = new GridData();
    selR1LData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
    selR1LData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    selR1LData.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;

    selR1Value = new Button(rGroup, SWT.NONE);
    selR1Value
            .setText("Select R1");
    selR1Value.setLayoutData(selR1LData);
    selR1Value.setEnabled(false);



    GridData r2LData = new GridData();
    r2LData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
    r2LData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    r2LData.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;        

    r2Numeric = new Button(rGroup, SWT.RADIO);
    r2Numeric.setText("Radio2");
    r2Numeric.setLayoutData(r2LData);
    r2Numeric.setSelection(false);
    r2Numeric.setEnabled(false);

    GridData selR2LData = new GridData();
    selR2LData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
    selR2LData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    selR2LData.verticalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;

    selR2Value = new Button(rGroup, SWT.NONE);
    selR2Value
            .setText("Select R2");
    selR2Value.setLayoutData(selR2LData);
    selR2Value.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code used to create the components (not only the check and radio buttons, but also the other components on the same page)?

Comment: Added sample code. apart from this I am using selectionListeners for every button. That will be again huge code to paste.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code provided is not exactly what you have on your machine, I could not reproduce your problem, but here I could traverse through all components.

Anyway, you can set the component's tab order.  Based on your example, try adding this code after creating everything:

```
rGroup.setTabList( new Control[] { checkBox1, r1Numeric, selR1Value, r2Numeric, selR2Value } );
```

Besides that, you could also implement, if it exists, the page's `setFocus` method, making it set focus on the checkbox.

Comment: Thank you, I made it by introducing another composite in the group.